# How do I use a mobile phone to open localhost:4200?

Tags: angular, localhost

My phone and pc are in same wifi. When I run `ng serve`, I open localhost:4200 in Chrome with my PC, which works.

But I open 192.168.1.107:4200 with my mobile phone, and it doesn’t work.

When I use `create-react-app`. It works.

Green is angular. White is react

[image: Green is angular.White is react]

Comment: Just to clarify, are you opening the app on 192.108.1.107:4200 or 192.168.1.107:4200?

Comment: it should work if it opens on the pc . there is something else thats bothering i guess

Comment: What is the IP address of your PC?  You should be opening up the same IP address as the PC.  If you use "localhost" on your mobile, it will try to open the server on your mobile.  You want to put in the address of your PC instead.

Comment: Is your PC's IP address really 192.1**0**8.1.107? It looks like a typo.

Comment: it's 192.168.1.107:4200

Comment: You can try your angular app. Open it with mobile phone .

Answer (score 43):

In order to make your server available in local network, you need to use the following command:

```
ng serve --host 192.168.1.107
```

And then the app will be available on `192.168.1.107:4200` on every device in your network.

If you don't know what is your LAN address you can execute `ifconfig | grep broadcast` on unix-based OS - the first IP is your computer, or `ipconfig` on Windows machine.

Comment: or just use `--host 0.0.0.0` and it will automatically pickup your IP

Comment: But you still need to know the address to open it :)

Answer (score 12):

- Phone OS - Android v.9
- Desktop OS - Windows 10
- Web browser (on both phone and desktop) - Google Chrome

---

1. Setup your mobile phone through this tutorial -> [Chrome Remote debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/)
2. Run your angular app by this comand `ng serve --public-host` (app should run on `localhost:4200`)
3. Ensure that your desktop and phone are connected to the same network
4. You need to do port forwarding, which is thanks to Chrome DevTools realy easy!

- Tutorial -> [Chrome Access Local Servers](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/local-server/)
- You need only to forward one port, you do it by clicking `Add rule` button which is located in `Remote devices` tab in the `settings` (see [Tutorial](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/local-server/)), then into `Device port` you write `4200` and into `Local address` you enter `localhost:4200`
- In my scenario I also needed to forward other port, because I was running my backend server on localhost too, my backend is running on `localhost:5010`, so I simply add new rule like i said above `Device Port: 5010` and `Local address: localhost:5010`

5. You can now visit `localhost:4200` on your phone and it should show your app

- The best part is that you can open the DevTools for the tab you have opened in your phone from the desktop DevTools and easily debug your page on phone from the Desktop (inspect the elements, see console, etc...) Your page will also be reloaded after change is made in the code...

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure whether this command changed in Angular 8, but *none* of these worked for me.

All I had to do was manually specify the port, et voilà!

```
ng s --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200
```

(Note that you can also use your actual IP address in place of `0.0.0.0`; both worked for me.)

Answer (score 2):

Your picture indicates that your PC's IP address is `192.168.1.107`. You stated that you're trying to access your angular app on the following IP:port combination:

```
192.108.1.107:4200
```

Assuming this isn't a typo, using the following IP:port combination `192.168.1.107:4200` should allow you to access your angular app.

Answer (score 1):

• Open in mobile

- `ng serve --host=0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check`
- `ng serve --host ip`

• Solution option (view backend data on mobile)

- Services section (Angular)
- Change domain name (localhost) to (ipHost)

Example

```
URI= " http://localhost:8080/... " [NO]

URI= " http://192.168.0.5:8080/... " [YES]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device)

If both your desktop and phone are connected to the same WiFi (or any other local network), then use your desktop IP address assigned by the router (not localhost and not 127.0.0.1).

To find out the IP address of your desktop:

- type into the command line ipconfig (Windows) or ifconfig (Unix)
- there's going to be a bunch of IP's
- try all of them (except the forementioned localhost and 127.0.0.1)

Answer (score 0):

If your phone and your computer connected to the same network (Wifi, LAN), you can use your computer local IP address (not the public IP address) to connect from your mobile to your computer.

Note: you should allow this in your computer firewall by adding inbound role to allow accessing your computer through your mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Linux machine + Android phone on the same wifi network:

1. **Get your machine IP**

> *ifconfig -a*
>
> ```
> .
> .
> wlp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
>       inet 192.168.1.199  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
> ```
>
> My machine results: network interface wlp3s0, IP 192.168.1.199

2. **Get your phone IP**

> ```
> consult your phone, 
> normally in Settings > About device > Status
>
> Result: my phone IP is 192.168.1.196
> ```

3. **Open port 4200 on interface wlp3s0 on your dev machine, your phone IP only**, as root:

> *ufw allow in on wlp3s0 from 192.168.1.196 to any port 4200*

**read ufw man page!!! - doing the wrong thing can open your machine to attacks**

> *ufw status*
>
> ```
>  Status: active
>
>  To                         Action      From
>  --                         ------      ---- 
>  4200 on wlp3s0             ALLOW       192.168.1.196
> ```

4. **Serve your app to 192.168.1.199**

> *ng serve --host 192.168.1.199*

5. **Connect from your desktop as well as from your phone to**

> 192.168.1.199:4200

6. **Alternative - serve to 0.0.0.0**

> *ng serve --host 0.0.0.0*
>
> from your machine: localhost:4200
>   from your phone: 192.168.1.199:4200

You may or may not need *--disable-host-check*

7. **Reset your firewall when done**

> ufw reset
>   ufw enable
>   ufw status

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com) to create a tunnel to have public URL. Install this program, open it with the command line by using next command:

```
ngrok http 3000
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally this would work like charm.

```
ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port <some-port>
```

If it doesn't it could be the Antivirus, in my case I turned off Avast and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

1. **Allow Inbound rule for 4200 in your PC/Laptop**

> Open your windows defender firewall on your windows system and crate a new inbound rule with TCP port 4200, then select your connection type and set rule name and description.

2. **Get your local machine's IP**

> Just open your command prompt in your local machine, and run the following command

```
ipconfig
```

3. **Make sure your local machine and your mobile connected**

> You can view localhost:4200 on your mobile, only if both devices are connected within the same network. So make sure your connection.

4. **Start your Angular application**

> Start your angular application with the following command

```
ng s --host <YOUR_IP>
```

5. **Open your web app**

> Now you can open your web app at "http://<YOUR_IP:4200>" on both local system and your mobile.

for detailed reference check this shorts video: [How to open localhost:4200 in mobile](https://youtube.com/shorts/hSdAUnOci7o?feature=share)

Comment: When linking to your own site or content (or content that you are affiliated with), you [must disclose your affiliation _in the answer_](/help/promotion) in order for it not to be considered spam. Having the same text in your username as the URL or mentioning it in your profile is not considered sufficient disclosure under Stack Exchange policy.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Besides the problem with spam, usually duplicate answers are not allowed in [StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415351/duplicate-answers-in-low-quality-answers-re-flag-or-delete) (I count at least 4 answers telling to do ng s --host), mainly if it is a late answer like yours...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the the page in ssl (https) use the following comand (may be as administrator):

> ng serve --ssl --host 0.0.0.0

Answer (score -1):

For the Same wifi connection of computer and mobile.

All these answers are right but they did not mention that the IP address must be the wifi IP.

if you run the program locally and your wifi is from a **Wi-Fi router** then the IP should be Wi-Fi IP.

**[Picture is Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1sW8.png)**